# Remove 00 values from TIME_FORMAT()

Tags: mysql, sql

From this query

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT("19:00:00", "%H Hours, %i Minutes, %s Seconds");
```

I get the result `19 Hours, 00 Minutes, 00 Seconds`

What i want to get is `19 Hours` Only if `Minutes and Seconds = 00`.

If i have `19:00:55` I expect to get `19 Hours, 55 Seconds`

And If i have `19:55:00` I expect to get `19 Hours, 55 Minutes`

by removing the `00` values using SQL

Comment: Try: `SELECT TIME_FORMAT("19:00:00", '%H Hours');`.

Comment: @wchiquito Updated the Question to Clarify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this:

```
SET @t = '19:00:00';

SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ', 
  CONCAT(NULLIF(TIME_FORMAT(@t, '%H'), '00'), ' hours'), 
  CONCAT(NULLIF(TIME_FORMAT(@t, '%i'), '00'), ' minutes'), 
  CONCAT(NULLIF(TIME_FORMAT(@t, '%s'), '00'), ' seconds')) AS time_expr;
```

Output:

```
+-----------+
| time_expr |
+-----------+
| 19 hours  |
+-----------+
```

When I set time to something else:

```
SET @t = '19:00:05';
```

Output:

```
+----------------------+
| time_expr            |
+----------------------+
| 19 hours, 05 seconds |
+----------------------+
```

It even handles zero hours:

```
SET @t = '00:43:00';
```

Output:

```
+------------+
| time_expr  |
+------------+
| 43 minutes |
+------------+
```

Comment: Is it possible to trim the leading `0` in single numebered values like `09` to become `9`?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a format for that in TIME_FORMAT(), so you may be able to do it with `TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM ...)`; See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Answer (score 4):

This is a slight variation of Bill's answer, which handles plurals on the time parts:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ', 
                 CONCAT(hour(t), ' hour', (case hour(t) when 0 then NULL when 1 then '' else 's' end)), 
                 CONCAT(minute(t), ' minute', (case minute(t) when 0 then NULL when 1 then '' else 's' end)), 
                 CONCAT(second(t), ' second', (case second(t) when 0 then NULL when 1 then '' else 's' end))
                ) AS time_expr
from (SELECT CAST('19:01:01' as time) as t) x
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this.

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT( "19:00:00", 
    CONCAT(IF(HOUR("19:00:00") <> 0, "%H Hours", "") ,
    IF(MINUTE("19:00:00") <> 0, ", %i Minutes", "") ,
    IF(SECOND("19:00:00") <> 0, ", %s Seconds", ""))
);
```